# How do I find a track by its name?

Tags: audacity

I have a project with a bunch of tracks, and I now want to edit one of them, but I don't know where it is. I know what it's called, however. How do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature to search for tracks in Audacity. However you can make it easier to search when you know the name:

1. Sort tracks by name using the **Tracks/Sort Tracks/by Name** menu option.
2. Select all (Ctrl + A / Command + A) to make the titles more readable while browsing.